# Matching python tag_name

Tags: python, if-statement

Hi I am trying to qualify a if statement by using the tag_name parameter in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(
    'http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215337195041/1/so_false')

products = []

div = driver.find_element_by_id('listings')
all_values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//div[@id="listings"] //a[@title] |//p[@class="subTitle"] | //span[@class="price"]/span | //strike[@class="wasprice"]| //p[@class="subTitle"]')


for item in all_values:
    if item.tag_name('span'):
        print(item.text.strip())
        i = i + 1

driver.close()
```

However i get the following error:

if item.tag_name('span'):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Is this the wrong sytnax? I cant seem to find the answer after searching.

Thanks!

Comment: where are `item` and `tag_name` coming from? Please post your entire code, including imports, so we can attempt to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: it looks like tag_name an attribute you are checking the value of. are you perhaps looking for item.tag_name == 'span'

Comment: That's it! wonderful thank you user2085282!